# Qt program to read text sees only one line in multi-line file

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextstream

I wrote a program to read a sequence of integer scores one per line in a text file. The file has a header which needs to be skipped.
Despite staring at this program, it only sees the first line (the header) and then behaves as if it's at the end.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

bool readScores(QString path)
{
  int line_count = 0;
  QFile qFile(path);
  if(!qFile.exists())
    {
      qDebug()<<"path does not exist:" << path;
      return false;
    }
  if(!qFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text)){
      qDebug("open fails");
      return false;
    }
  QTextStream ts(&qFile);
  qDebug()<<ts.readLine();// just read the head...
  while(!qFile.atEnd())
    {
      line_count++;
      int score;
      QTextStream tsLine;
      QString line = ts.readLine(512);
      tsLine.setString(&line);
      tsLine >> score;
      qDebug()<<"Just read"<<score;
    }
  qDebug()<<"found "<<line_count<<" lines";
  qFile.close();
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  readScores("e:/tmp/scores.txt");
  return a.exec();
}
```

And here is the content of scores.txt:

```
just test data
69
48
38
2
5
1
1
4
```

Here is the program's output

```
"just test data"
found  0  lines
```

Can you see why the program does not see the 8 lines of scores?
I'm using Qt 5.3.1 on Windows with Mingw32

Answer (score 2):

When you use QTextStream you should no longer use QFile:

```
bool readScores(QString path)
{
    [...]
    QTextStream ts(&qFile);
    qDebug()<<ts.readLine();// just read the head...
    QString line;
    do
    {
        line = ts.readLine();
        bool ok;
        int score = line.toInt(&ok);
        if(ok){
            qDebug()<<"Just read"<<score;
            line_count++;
        }
    }
    while (!line.isNull());
    qDebug()<<"found "<<line_count<<" lines";
    qFile.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I found the error from your first sentence, but it seems the fix can be just to replace qFile.atEnd() by ts.atEnd().